# Cypress - Element not found

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

How can I overcome a situation when the element is not found. I am automating a form where intentionally I am giving a duplicate name so an error message will be shown "Limit Name already exist" based on that I have written

```js
   add.limitName().type('Movie Limits') // Giving duplicate name "Movie Limits"

   cy.get('.has-error > .col-sm-6 > [data-bv-validator="remote"]').then((wizard) => {
       if(wizard.text().includes('Limit Name already exist.'))  // Duplicate Limit Name Check
       {
           add.limitName().clear()
           add.limitName().type('Movie TR Limits')   // Giving another Name
       }
     })
```

This works perfectly fine if its a duplicate value but if its not a duplicate value then this element wont be found and an error is thrown and the test fails. How can i write in such a way if its not duplicate it carries on and if it is the above code comes into action ?

Comment: Are you wanting to reuse this piece of code in for submitting forms with duplicates and unique limit names?

Comment: Yes....duplicate and unique litmit names

Answer (score 1):

It seems perfectly legit for the test to fail when the error is missing, but to answer your question

Split off the last selector and check it with jQuery (which does not cause a fail) instead of including it in the Cypress `cy.get()`.

```js
cy.get('.has-error > .col-sm-6')
  .then($col => {
    // test the last element with jquery by checking it's length
    if ($col.find('[data-bv-validator="remote"]').length === 0) {
      ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use another selector other than `.has-error` if that class may or may not exist.

```js
cy.get('my-selector').then($el => {
  if ($el.hasClass('has-error')) {

    cy.get('.has-error > .col-sm-6 > [data-bv-validator="remote"]')
      .then(wizard => {
        ...
      })

  } else {
    ...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the error class after the `.type()` command

```js
add.limitName().type('Movie Limits') 
  .then($el => {

    if ($el.hasClass('has-error')) {

      cy.get('.has-error > .col-sm-6 > [data-bv-validator="remote"]')
        .then((wizard) => { ...
        });
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the element with `.has-class` is ***not*** the `<input>` you type into, use `.parent()` to check if the class is present.

```js
add.limitName().type('Movie Limits') 

cy.get('[data-bv-validator="remote"]')
  .parent()                            // up to ".col-sm-6"
  .parent()                            // up to element which (maybe) has ".has-error"
  .then($el => 

    if ($el.hasClass('has-error')) {

      cy.get('.has-error > .col-sm-6 > [data-bv-validator="remote"]')
        .then((wizard) => { ...
        });
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that when there is no error the element `.has-error` itself won't exist in the dom. So you can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('body').then(($body) => {
  if ($body.find('.has-error').length > 0) {
    //Element found
    cy.get('.has-error').should('include.text', 'Limit Name already exist.')
    add.limitName().clear()
    add.limitName().type('Movie TR Limits')
  } else {
    //Error element not found.Write further code.
  }
})
```